# Compiz is not applying config from CompizConfig Settings Manager

Tags: gnome, compiz, fedora-14

I use Fedora 14 with Compiz on Gnome.

I'd like to change some settings of Compiz with CompizConfig Settings Manager, but when I change a setting in there, those settings are not being applied.

Sometimes, Compiz seems to "forget" that I made changes.
Loging out and back in doesn't help, as well as reboots
CompizConfig shows the changes settings in the plugin preferences, but they just don't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled apon this when I had the same problem.  Run the command:

```
compiz-manager
```

Add it to your startup applications in System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications.

Comment: didn't solve the issue. Also, my Compiz setting are being applied instantly otherwise.

Comment: `compiz-manager` doesn't exist for me and `sudo apt install compiz-manager` finds nothing.